# Nginx / PHP / ZF2 Have Routing issue of extension like ".php"

Tags: php, nginx, zend-framework2

Thanks in Advance for the help.

I have issue in nginx with php + ZF2

We build application with appache and now we want to swift in nginx and we are facing issue like below.

In which my conf file as below.

```
server {

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/xmlhub/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name nginx.xmlhub;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        #fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

      }

    location ~ .*\.(git|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf|ico)?$ {
        expires 30d;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$ {
        expires 1h;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

My product have lots of url with extension ".php" so, i cant remove that.

like below my ZF2 Code snap

```
'common' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                     'route' => '/common/index.php[?action=:action][&id=:id][&page=:page][&country=:country][&img=:img]',

                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Common\Controller\Index',
                        'action' => 'login',
                        'page' => 1,
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
//                     'query' => array('type' => 'query'),
                ),
            ),
```

I have found error on each page who have php extensions.

[image]

Thanks & Regards

Comment: I have tried your config and it works here. Can you confirm that the file /usr/share/nginx/html/xmlhub/public/common/index.php exists and is readable?

Comment: Yeah, file is exist at that location and this code is working under apache but i have issue with nginx and those url have php extention